# Media Editor uppercase extensions to lowercase

Tags: images

What's the reason for making the extensions on uploaded images lowercase as soon as the upload is complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File names on UNIX or Linux are case sensitive. Rewrite rules or the simple check for duplicate file names are much more reliable when the extensions are unified during the file upload.